# Getting proper logs from Elastic Beanstalk (Spring Boot)

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, logging, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm running a Spring Boot application in Elastic Beanstalk.
I find exploring the logs in Elastic Beanstalk somewhat unintuitive.
I'm only presented with 2 options, download all logs, or the last 100 lines, Which has the logs for my applications and for the EC2 instance that Elastic Beanstalk runs in.
Is there a way to see my application logs (the same logs I see in my local machine when running the application) without being limited to the last 100 lines and the other noise, or having to download all the logs each time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must create Log group for your Elastic Beanstalk in the first place.
Then Go to the console of the created Elastic BeanStalk and click on the application. Once inside the application onto your left you can see `Configuration`. Click on `Configuration`. The first Configuration box is named `Software`. In the box you can see the Log Group and a link to the cloudwatch logs for that application. Click on that, it will directly take you to cloudwatch logs where you can get all the logs in one place.